# Why isn't the snap for zoom-client at the latest version?

Tags: snap, 23.04, zoom-meeting

To join a meeting that I was recently invited, I installed `zoom-client` using `snap install`. However, after running it I, realized that the snap version is several releases behind the one provided on zoom.us download page. Why is this so and what is the recommended method to install the latest zoom-client?

Note: I know the pros and cons of just downloading and installing the `.deb` version from the download site and re-downloading and re-installing it each time a new version is released. However, I was surprised to see that the "snap" version is several releases behind and this seems to be contrary to the concept advertised for snaps.

[image]

Comment: The *stable* version is `5.14.7.2928` but I also see `5.14.10.3738` with details on how to download that version at https://snapcraft.io/zoom-client

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look with the `snap info` command:

```
$ snap info zoom-client
name:      zoom-client
summary:   ZOOM Cloud Meetings
publisher: Oliver Grawert (ogra)
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/zoom-client
license:   Proprietary
description: |
  Video conferencing with real-time messaging and content sharing
  
  https://zoom.us provides simplified video conferencing, whiteboard sharing
  and messaging across any device. This is an unofficial re-pack of the debian
  package provided by zoom.us
snap-id: 76rrD7USwCJrZgepbRk7UdFEWON3tVKX
channels:
  latest/stable:    5.14.7.2928  2023-05-30 (205) 367MB -
  latest/candidate: 5.14.7.2928  2023-05-30 (205) 367MB -
  latest/beta:      5.14.7.2928  2023-05-30 (205) 367MB -
  latest/edge:      5.14.10.3738 2023-06-06 (206) 368MB -
```

As you can see, version 5.14.10 is available from the `edge`-channel and can be installed with `snap install --edge zoom-client`.

Comment: I guess, here "egde" means something like "beta of beta"? Or something else?

Comment: They could have called it "alpha"... It's just the channel where newest software goes for testing. I think one might experience some bugs, but it's also possible that it runs just fine.

Comment: Also bear in mind that the snap isn't packaged by Zoom but by a member of the community (as it the case with many snaps), so you're reliant on a volunteer finding time to do it after Zoom release a new version.

Comment: In case you have already installed zoom, you can update to the latest version by `snap refresh --edge zoom-client`